# Recursive Fibonacci MIPS

Tags: c, assembly, mips, fibonacci, mips32

I started to read MIPS to understand better how my C++ and C code works under the computer skin. I started with a recursive function, a Fibonacci function.
The C code is:

```
int fib(int n) {
if(n == 0) { return 0; }
if(n == 1) { return 1; }
return (fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2));
}
```

MIPS code:

```
fib:
addi $sp, $sp, -12 
sw $ra, 8($sp) 
sw $s0, 4($sp)

addi $v0, $zero, $zero
beq $a0, $zero, end
addiu $v0, $zero, 1
addiu $t0, $zero, 1 
beq $a0, $t0, end
addiu $a0, $a0, -1
sw $a0, 0($sp) 
jal fib #fib(n-1)
addi $s0, $v0, $zero 
lw $a0, 0($sp) 
addiu $a0, $a0, -1
jal fib #fib(n-2)
add $v0, $v0, $s0

end:
lw $s0, 4($sp)
lw $ra, 8($sp) 
addi $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra
```

When `n>1` it goes until the code reaches the first `jal` instruction. What happens next? it return to `fib` label ignoring the code below (the fib(n-2) call will never be executed?)? If that happens, the `$sp` pointer decreases 3 words again and the cycle will go until `n<=1`.  I can't understand how this works when first `jal` instruction is reached.

Comment: It eventually returns to the return address after `jal`.  Also, remember that real MIPS has branch-delay slots.  If you want GCC to only fill them with NOPs instead of real instructions (so the code would run the same on a simplified MIPS without), use `-fno-delayed-branch`.  [Tweak mips-gcc output to work with MARS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052444).  Also, if you compile with `gcc -Og -fverbose-asm`, that might help to annotate the asm with comments.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

Answer (score 1):

Can you follow how the recursion works in C?

In some sense, recursion has two components: the forward part and the backward part.  In the forward part, a recursive algorithm computes things before the recursion, and in the backward part, a recursive algorithm computes things after the recursion completes.  In between the two parts, there is the recursion.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71551098/471129

Fibonacci is just slightly more complicated as it performs recursion twice, not just once as in the above list printing example.

However, the principles are the same:  There is work done before the recursion, and work done after (either of which can be degenerate).  The before part happens as code in front of the recursion executes, and the recursion builds up stack frames that are placeholders for work after the recursion yet to be completed.  The after part happens as the stack frames are released and the code after the recursive call is executed.

In any given call chain, the forward part goes until n is 0 or 1, then the algorithm starts returning back to the stacked callers, for whom the backward part kicks in unwinding stack frames until it returns to the original caller (perhaps `main`) rather than to some recursive `fib` caller.  Again, complicated by use of two recursive invocations rather than one as in simpler examples.

With fib, the work done before is to count down (by -1 or -2) until reaching 0 or 1.  The work done after the recursion is to sum the two prior results.  The recursion itself effectively suspends an invocation or activation of `fib` with current values, to be resumed when a recursive call completes.

---

Recursion in MIPS algorithm is the same; however, function operations are spread out over several machine code instructions that are implicit in C.

---

Suggest single stepping over a call to `fib(2)` as a very small example that may help you see what's going on there.  Suggest first doing this in C — single step until the outer `fib` call has full completed and returned to the calling test function (e.g. `main`).

To make the C version just a bit easier to view in the debugger you might use this version:

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    if (n == 1) { return 1; }
    int fm1 = fib(n-1);
    int fm2 = fib(n-2);
    int result = fm1 + fm2;
    return result;
}
```

With that equivalent C version, you'll be able to inspect `fm1`, `fm2`, and `result` during single stepping.  That will make it easier to follow.

Next, do the same in the assembly version.  Debug single step to watch execution of `fib(2)`, and draw parallels with the equivalents in C.

---

There's another way to think about recursion, which is ignore the recursion, pretending that the recursive call is to some unrelated function implementation that just happens to yield the proper results of the recursive function; here's such a non-recursive function:

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    if (n == 1) { return 1; }
    int fm1 = fibX(n-1);   // calls something else that computes fib(n-1)
    int fm2 = fibX(n-2);   //   "
    int result = fm1 + fm2;
    return result;
}
```

With this code, and the assumption that `fibX` *simply works correctly to return proper results*, you can focus strictly on the logic of one level, namely, the body of this `fib`, without considering the recursion at all.

Note that we can do the same in assembly language — though the opportunities for errors / typos are always much larger than in the C, since you still have to manipulate stack frames and preserve critical storage for later use after the calling.

---

The code you've posted has a transcription error, making it different from the C version.  It is doing the C equivalent of:

```
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-1);
```

---

Let's go back to this somewhat more explicit version:

```
int fib(int n) {                  // n defined upon entry
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    if (n == 1) { return 1; }
    int fm1 = fib(n-1);           // fm1 defined
    int fm2 = fib(n-2);           // n used to compute n-2
    int result = fm1 + fm2;       // fm1 used
    return result;
}
```

For assembly language, an analysis of the variables must be performed so that we use the proper registers and stack frame memory.

First, let's observe that `n` is "live" across a function call, namely the function call of `fib(n-1)`.  This is an important property.  Function calling wipes out certain registers and so it is important to preserve things that are defined before a function call and used after.  Here the value of `n` is defined as a parameter, so can be thought of as being defined already upon entry.  It is used in doing `fib(n-1)` and that is not of concern, however it is also used doing `fib(n-2)` — to compute `n-2` and that computation takes place after the call to `fib(n-1)`.  So, `n` needs special storage that will survive the first function call.

What else is live across a function call?  It is `fm1`, since it defined before the call to `fib(n-2)` and used after.  So, `fm1` also needs function-surviving storage.

And yet what else?  We don't see it in C but in assembly the return address is exposed to us as an additional function parameter, and like `n` it is considered defined upon function entry.  That incoming parameter value (the return address) must survive both function calls, as it is used at the end to accomplish the `return` operation.

This liveness/storage analysis is necessary whether using the version with explicit variables or the simpler version that uses internal temporary variables implicit in `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`.

Let's further note that this analysis is identical for the `fibX` non-recursive version, as all the requirements of register preservation come from function calling regardless of recursion.  (there are opportunities for optimization of the calling convention if we know the implementation of both caller and callee, but we choose not to employ those in these learning scenarios).

So, what we need to do is create some stack space for the function to use, and in that stack space, store `$ra`, which is the return address, and store `$a0`, which is `n`, and also provide room for variable `fm1` (or the temporary in that version).  Later, `fm1` needs to be stored to memory after it is defined, while `n` needs to be reloaded from memory in order to compute `n-2`, for the next recursive call.  After the 2nd recursive call, `fm1` can be reloaded, the return value computed, and finally the return address is reloaded, stack frame is released, and the function can return to its caller.

Let's also note that `fm2` and `result` are relatively simple in comparison, neither needs to survive a function call, so these can use call clobbered registers or be used from the register where they appear.